# Need Help deploying my CLI application in Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, command-line

I've developed a command line application that takes a URL as input and utilizes the Lighthouse package to provide performance, SEO, and accessibility metrics for the given webpage.

I've taken the steps to dockerize this application and successfully deployed it within a Kubernetes.

environment. While I've deployed web applications in Kubernetes before, the method I typically use doesn't seem to be applicable to CLI applications. So I am not able to access my deployed application.

So, how do i deploy it in kubernetes such that other people will be able to use it in their command line.

this is github repo: [https://github.com/rohanmaharjan100/lighthouse.git](https://stackoverflow.com)
this is docker file:

```
FROM node:current-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
FROM node:current-alpine
RUN apk add chromium
EXPOSE 4000
COPY --from=builder /app /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true \
    PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "index.js"]
```

This is Deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: lighthouse-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: lighthouse
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: lighthouse
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: lighthouse
          image: rohanmaharjan100/lighthouse:v1-release
          args:
            - "npx"
            - "get"
            - "--url"
            - "https://facebook.com"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4000
```

I was hoping it to be deployed in such a way that other people can use this application in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Kubernetes this way (and I might not use Docker either).

A typical recipe for getting access to things in Kubernetes is to create an Ingress object that forwards to a Service that forwards to Pods; but, this requires your application have an HTTP interface.  An ordinary user can't connect to a CLI program running in the cluster.

Someone with privileged access to the cluster could in principle run [`kubectl attach`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#attach) to be able to type input into the program.  If the program doesn't accept interactive input then someone with privileged access to the cluster could run [`kubectl logs`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs) to see its output (and the program would be better run as a Job).  In both cases the user would need to have access to the Kubernetes API server, which is usually protected, and that could give the user permission to see or modify other things inside the cluster besides this specific application.

For an application as you describe it, an approach I might actually look into is [uploading it to npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/contributing-packages-to-the-registry).  Then the end user experience is just

```bash
sudo npm install --global @rohanmaharjan100/lighthouse  # once only
lighthouse-seo npx get --url https://stackoverflow.com
```

and you don't need root permissions or remote cluster access to be able to run it.

Comment: Actually we are trying to implement this application in our CD pipeline to get performance and SEO of web pages. So any idea how this program can be implemented there?